# Python - matplotlib: Trying to animate decision boundary plot without points being animated

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
def sequential_deltaRule(X, W, T, maxEpoch):
    learningRate = 0.001
    currentEpoch = 1
    while currentEpoch <= maxEpoch:
        for index, xCol in enumerate(X.T):
            Wdelta = -learningRate * np.dot(np.dot(W[0], xCol) - T[index], xCol.T)
            W = W + Wdelta
        currentEpoch += 1
    return W

def plotclass(lhs, rhs):
    x, y = lhs[0], lhs[1]
    k, l = rhs[0], rhs[1]
    plt.scatter(x, y, color='black')
    plt.scatter(k, l, color='red')
    plt.show()
    return None


def plotBoundary(weights):
    x = np.linspace(-1.5, 3, 100)
    y = -(weights[1] * x + weights[0]) / weights[2]
    #fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.plot(x, y, color='blue')


def generateData(datapoints):
    n = datapoints
    mA, sigmaA = np.array([2.0, 1]), np.array([0.3, 0.3])
    mB, sigmaB = np.array([-0.1, 0.0]), np.array([0.3, 0.3])
    classA = (np.random.normal(size=(2, n)).T * sigmaA + mA).T
    classB = (np.random.normal(size=(2, n)).T * sigmaB + mB).T
    return classA, classB

W1 = sequential_deltaRule(data, weights, targets, 20)[0]
plotBoundary(W1)
plotclass(classA, classB)
```

I'm trying to plot the points from the two classes and then animate the decision boundary. But at this moment I only get one image.

What I'm trying to do is like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RgoHTMbp4A&t=306s&ab_channel=NeuralNine but I dont want the points to animate, only the deicison boundary.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am trying to animate the boundaries"? The code does not contain any animation. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: In "def sequential_deltaRule" i am looping and doing Delta rule algorithm, creating a decision boundary that separates the two groups of input points acting as two classes. So the task in university is to animate the steps of the decision boundary. In the example video on youtube he does this but i dont want to animate the points as well being placed on the plot.

Comment: As far as I can see, this function calculates changes but does not animate or even plot them. But difficult to know without a reproducible code example. We only know what you post here, so if any part is missing to reproduce your problem (like imported libraries, input data, etc.), your chance of getting a good answer will decrease.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.